# What is the form action equivalent in Angular 4/6/7?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a payment gateway that I need to embed in my angular application. I have to add a form tag in my page, where after a valid checkout ID is received (there is some JS code I have to inject which sends a request to the payment server with an amount to be charged, and it will reply with a valid checkout id), a card will be shown.

According to their documentation, I have to then send a form ACTION to the page I wish to navigate to after the user clicks on PAY.

```
<form action="https://myurl.com/nextpage/" class="paymentWidgets" 
      data-brands="VISA MASTER">
</form>
```

Right now I have hardcoded the action URL in the form. How do I make this dynamic? according to angular documentation, they do not recommend using form action anymore and instead expect us to do that within the code. But since, I don't have any control on this form, I need some way of making the URL dynamic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `ngNoForm` directive with property binding `[action]="url"` with the dynamic URL which you can change from your component.

**Example**

**component.html**

```
  <form ngNoForm  [action]="url" method="POST"
      target="_blank" class="paymentWidgets" data-brands="VISA MASTER">
      <input type="text">
       <button type="submit">Sumbmit</button>
  </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Dynamic Form Action Demo';
  url ="https://myurl.com/nextpage/";
}
```

**[Here is Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blvbj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Hope this will help!